# Animating in Photoshop with transparency

Tags: png, gif

How to make a "Graphics Interchange Format" as Transparent in Photoshop or any other tool ?

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp - this is a limitation of the GIF format.

Comment: Is it possible in Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop, whatever is transparent in the document will be transparent in a GIF or PNG image.

Simply use transparency in your layers within Photoshop and when you Save For Web as a GIF or PNG, that transparency is seen and used. There are no special steps you need to take to ensure transparency transfers to the final image.

Comment: What about the "default" all-white locked background layer? Hide/delete it?

Comment: Simply remove it. It's only "default" if you set it to white in the New Document window.