# Gimp: Howto antialias round border around

Tags: gimp, anti-aliasing

I have a gif file with a round logo on top of transparent background. The border around the round item needs to be antialiased.

I have tried selecting with the fuzzy wand as well as with border: 2px, but either case I'm not able to choose Color to Alpha nor Blur Gaussian Blur as suggested in many tutorials.

I have also tried changing the format of the file to xcf

Any ideas? Gimp 2.6.12 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

The GIF specifications do not allow semi-transparency which would be needed for anti-aliasing a border to the transparent background.

To overcome this you may generate a fake semi-transparency by dithering the output on exporting to GIF (see my answer to this question: [GIF with transparency output not as expected in GIMP](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp)). The resulting image qualtity may be far from expected. In case you are not happy you will need to use another image format supporting semi-transparency (e.g. PNG).

To be able to use the Blur filters, and then to add an alpha channel we will have to convert the *Image > Mode* from *Indexed...* to *RGB* first.