# Gimp animations screws up transparency!

Tags: gimp

~I've attempted several tries at every option to have my transparent png's to become an animated gif. It either combines main pieces that remain the same as the rest are black and combining other similar frames, or it is combining them all without replacing. I've checked and unchecked every option and combination, it does not seem to be happening. I've done this project with these images before. Also, it seems to be a recurring problem, off and on that is.

Comment: Can you attach a sample image, or multiple ones demonstrating the results you got? And please try to reformat a question, using e.g. paragraphs to indicate what you want to achieve, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Does this Q & A help: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Do some of your PNGs have areas of partial transparency?  That could be the source of the problem, since GIFs don't support partial transparency - only full transparency, or full opacity.  If so it has nothing to do with GIMP - just a limitation of the GIF format itself.

Answer (score 1):

This should b no problem if you force all the frames to `(replace)` mode, either explicitly in the layer names, or by ticking the `Use disposal entered above for all frames` in the export dialog.

Two possible pitfalls:

- this assumes that the frames are really fully opaque where they should. GIFs can be optimized, and this often results into transparent pixels where the pixels in Frame N+1 is the same color as in Frame N (Frame N+1 is then usually smaller than the image, contains transparent pixels and is in `(combine)` mode. So if you started with a GIF, make sure it is unoptimized: all frames should be in `(replace)` mode. You can ensure this with `Filters>Animation>Unoptimize`.
- Unlike PNG, the GIF format doesn't support partial opacity, pixels are either fully opaque or fully transparent. So the partial opacity from your PNG is thresholded. This at best leads to pixellated edges, but in some bad cases this make the picture look very different