# opacity not altering in for GIF in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency, gif

I have got a water file for a game I am creating (its currently a gif), I import the GIF into GIMP by using *import as layers*. The GIF then appears as this:

[image]

I then altered the opacity of each of the frames to 20 so that the opacity effect happens:
[image]

I then added an alpha channel (which occurs for all frames)
[image]

Then I change the colour mode from indexed to RGB:
[image]

I then save the file as a GIF and add the following options to allow each frame to appear one at a time:
[image]

But after all of this the opacity does not show (It might be hard to see but its not transparent):
[image]

Does anyone know why this perhaps might not be working.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. GIF's don't support semi-transparency (or alpha transparency) because they use Indexed colour which only allows for 1bit transparency, either fully on or fully off.

Comment: This Q & A may also help you: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp

Comment: @Takkat - yeah I think that's probably a duplicate question. Well spotted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIF with transparency output not as expected in GIMP](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp)

Comment: @BillyKerr I found a way around it. I converted the GIF into separate PNG frames and then altered each of them and then put them back into a GIF.

Comment: How did that work? gif simply does not support 'partial transparency'. If you change your background colour, you'll see. if you simply wanted it lighter against an always white background, then you could do it without any transparency at all, lightening the graphics load too.

Comment: @Tetsujin I got a converter that converted the GIF into separate frames that were all PNG and then altered the opacity of each frame, added the alpha channel and colour mode RGB and presto, I had what I needed!

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 - but you still won't be able to export a GIF as RGBa since the format only supports Indexed colour.  Sounds like you might want to have a look at exporting as APNG.

Comment: @BillyKerr Trust me. It worked. That's all that matters.